# Migrate jaxws-maven-plugin from Java 7 to Java 17

Tags: java, migration, wsdl, pom.xml, jax-ws

I am using this configuration in Java 7

```
<plugin>
       <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
       <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.3</version>
       <executions>
       <execution>
            <id>1</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                 <xadditionalHeaders>true</xadditionalHeaders>
                 <executable>${tool.wsimport}</executable> 
             <wsdlDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
            <target>2.1</target>
            </configuration>
            </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I must migrate it to Java 17, changing version I receive these error

```
[WARNING] Failed to build parent project for com.sun.xml.ws:project:pom:2.2.8
Failed to build parent project for com.sun.xml.ws:project:pom:2.2.8
Failed to build parent project for com.sun.xml.ws:bundles:pom:2.2.8
Failed to build parent project for com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:pom:2.2.8
Invalid POM for com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:jar:2.2.8, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
```

I've tried to migrate using the solutions for Java 11 migrations. But they doesn't work. I've also tried to add dependencies manually, download jars... but without results. I can't find migration guide to Java 17. Any help?